# ngx-translate load translations from multiple sources

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-translate

My application has modules loaded as libraries, we are using ngx-translate, what I want is for one module the translations are getting loaded from a API for which locale is sent as param. Rest of the other modules translations come from /assests folder.

I see that default path can be overrided by

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "/public/lang-files/", "-lang.json");
}
```

But this expects translations file name  en-us.json, fr-ca.json format, but what I want is lang.json irrespective of language locale will be sent as parameter to the request. Is there a way to load in this

Comment: Have you tried to implement [your own](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#write--use-your-own-loader) TranslationLoader?

Comment: Well if that is only option I will, I was looking if there are any existing options.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way out

loader

```
export class dyamicTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private prefix: string = 'en') {}
  public getTranslation(lang: string): any {
    return this.http.get('/assets/data/' + lang + '.json');
  }
}

export function dynamicTransLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new dyamicTranslateLoader(http, 'en-us');
}

TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: dynamicTransLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
```

And whenever you want to change language

```
this.translateSvc.use('fr-ca');
```